# How do I equip my Lava Rod on Roblox fishing simulator?

Tags: roblox

So, on roblox there is the game called Fishing Simulator. There is a lava obby you can do to get the lava rod. I completed the obby and opened the chest and it didn't give me my lava rod, just the achievement. How do I get it back?

Comment: I don't play roblox anymore, but I know there can be multiple worlds under the same name, wouldn't it be better to provide a link to said game you are looking for assistance with?

Answer (score 0):

Click on your backpack, then go to skins and pick "lava rod"!